# how image in qweb report by fields.function

Tags: python, odoo, qweb

im trying to show images in a wqeb report trough a fields.function.
inside a form everything goes well, but when a try in qweb report trow this error,
still I do not understand the meaning of this error.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
  File "/opt/ikom/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 791, in value_to_html
raise ValueError("Non-image binary fields can not be converted to HTML")
```

ValueError: Non-image binary fields can not be converted to HTML

am trying to get by this way

```
   'chart': fields.function(_get_image, string="Grafica de pallets", type="binary"),


    def _get_image(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context=None):
       pdb.set_trace()
       res = dict.fromkeys(ids)
       for record_browse in self.browse(cr, uid, ids):
          partner = self.pool.get('res.partner').browse(cr,uid,6,context=None).image
          res[record_browse.id] = base64.encodestring(chart_encoded)
       return res

<span itemprop="image" t-field="o.chart" t-field-options='{"widget": "image", "alt-field": "name"}'/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get images from db by fields.function on QWeb report - Odoo 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34026022/get-images-from-db-by-fields-function-on-qweb-report-odoo-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should replace your function field with `binary` field and  add something like this :

```
<span t-field="o.image_field" t-field-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;image&quot;, &quot;class&quot;: &quot;img-rounded&quot;}"/>
```

Comment: thanks man, my intention to use in this way, its because i get params from wizard and i want to use osv.osv_Memory in my class type.
its solved for now using osv.osv as my clas type, but a dont want to make real table, just a memory table.
thans in advance